# How to use custom delegate for xib in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, custom-keyboard

I want to use inputAccessoryView to add custom number buttons above the keyboard. And I have added the view. I have assigned the class CustomKeyboard to the xib file. Within the CustomKeyboard class file, I have connected the IBAction of the buttons. I have two textFields in my ViewController textField1 & textFiled2 & I have associated inputAccessoryView with textField1. When I am tapping on textField1 then my custom buttons are shown above the keyboard. My goal is when I tap on my custom button it should enter the value in textFild2. But I really don't have any idea how would I achieve this. Anybody has some idea plz help me out.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class CustomKeyboard:UIView {
    @IBAction func rowButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.currentTitle)
    }
    
}

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let view = UINib(nibName: "CustomKeyboard", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        textField1.inputAccessoryView = view//customView
        textField1.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField2.autocorrectionType = .no
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This lacks clarity. Can you not assign the `textField2.inputAccessoryView = view` directly?

Comment: no I don't wanna tap to textField2 as It would be handled by textField1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegates or closures to get call back from CustomKeyboard to ViewController. Example below uses delegate method and function rowTapped will be called when user taps on view.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CustomKeyBoardProtocol:AnyObject{
        fun rowTapped(title:String)
}
class CustomKeyboard:UIView {

weak var delegate:CustomKeyBoardProtocol?
    @IBAction func rowButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.currentTitle)
        delegate.rowTapped(title: sender.currentTitle)
    }

}

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,  CustomKeyBoardProtocol{
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let customView = UINib(nibName: "CustomKeyboard", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CustomKeyboard
        customView.delegate = self// he
        textField1.inputAccessoryView = customView//customView
        textField1.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField2.autocorrectionType = .no
    }


    func rowTapped(title:String){//it will be called on tap
    }
}
```